# How to determine Canadian patent life-time?

Tags: patent-infringement

Is patent CA 2561773 A1 still valid or pending?
Event shows: dead in 2008
Please inform of risk of patent infringement.

Answer (score 1):

Citing the [Canadian patent office website](https://www.ic.gc.ca/opic-cipo/cpd/eng/help/content/help_administrative_status.html) as reached through the Google Patents link on "dead" applications:

> The date that an abandoned application could normally no longer be reinstated.
>
> Dead Application  2009-09-21

Unless the owner is in a coma and can therefore reinstate the right after waking up (I don't know if this is possible in Canada), the patent application is most probably "dead".

Comment: I think it cannot be reinstate the dead patent, only if the application erroneously became dead

Comment: Just a little nit to pick, but I hate when applications are referred to as patents.